# how can i add UDID of device in Chartboost account for testing interstitial ads

Tags: ios, ads, chartboost

I am using chartboost in my app but I am facing problem with ads. How can I add the UDID of a device to a Chart boost account? My ads are not showing every time, how can I test ads on my real device?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chartboost has a "testing mode" for ads so you don't need to add "testing devices" like other networks.

Inside the app page, select enabled for Test Mode:
[image]

Comment: But what if I want a specific device to be always on test mode? Just maybe 2-3 devices only, how do I do that..?